# How can i clear cache before upload new file on S3 with nodejs?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am uploading same name file on aws s3 which has been used in multiple websites and due to aws s3 cache feature i am unable to clear cache before uploading file. Please help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: There is no S3 cache feature, if you're uploading the file with the name, it'll overwrite the existing one if no versioning is enabled and if versioning is enabled, the new file will become the latest version replacing the existing one which will become a version. Are you using CloudFront to serve S3 files because that could cause caching related problems ?

Comment: yes i am using CloudFront.

Comment: In this case, make invalidation right after upload the file. You can run a lambda function to make invalidation for you for a new PUT in S3 bucket.https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html

Comment: @JamesDean I have seen the documentation but don't know how to implement in nodejs. There is no syntax or pseudocode. If you have implemented it somewhere please suggest. Thanks.
***I think it require extra fee.***